# regarding the directory that is to be used for gets() and puts() function

Tags: c++

my question is that what kind of directory should be used for gets() and puts() function.because i'm getting an error when i use gets() function in some of the programs.. and in other program it compiles without any error message..but the directory which i used for both the programs were same.and when i replace the gets() with cin,it runs.. for example,

```
cout<<"enter the name of the student"; 
fflush(stdin);
gets(name);
```

i get a error message in fflush(stdin) and gets()..so remove fflush() and gets() and replace it with cin..therefore my program compiles with zero errors and then it runs... 
but y not when fflush() and gets() are used?

Comment: have you included stdio.h ? or cstdio ?

Comment: i have included iostream and using namespace std;.

Comment: also include cstdio or stdio.h.

Comment: Please clarify your question.